# Hold same queries and only forward one unique query to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, 100 same queries `SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE columnA LIKE '%STH%'` sent to MySQL simultaneously, and MySQL will execute those 100 same queries at the same time.

Is there some middleware or plugins, can hold all these 100 queries and only sent one query to MySQL, wait for result and sent results to all clients?

Memcache is not the option. If query not hit in Memcache, there is a chance that MySQL will execute all 100 same queries.

Comment: To send the query using PHP, Java or other language?

Comment: I think it is language independent.

Comment: I say this because it can be validated before the existence of a file which stores the answer to the first query arrives.

Comment: Why mysql native query cache is not an option?